# How to add a hard coded value to an object in a class from unit test for testing purpose

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, static-methods

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetTerm()
{
    Response resp = new Response(); 
    resp = InfomationController.GetTermAndCond(); //line 'LI001'
    return Ok(resp);
} 
[TestMethod]
public void GetTerm_FromGetTerm()
{
    var controller = new ServController();
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.GetTerm();

    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
}
```

In here above Response class act as a template that adds another field(massage) according to the values added to it by `GetTermAndCond();` (static method).

1. I want to know how can I properly write a unit test to this when
   there is a static method.
2. Is there any way that I can add a value to **line 'LI001'**  from
   the test method and check whether this gives the necessary response accordingly.

P.S.- The source code cannot be changed no matter what. I know this can be a duplicate for some perspective but I surf through stack so many times and didn't find a solution. So it will be a great help if some one can find an answer to this.

Comment: If you can't change the code, you can use Microsoft Fakes to fake out static methods (for example, I tend to use it to fake the value of `DateTime.Now`). However, you should really restructure your code to avoid static methods, and instead provide the value using a service interface (e.g. `IInformationControllerService`). Note that other fakeing tools are available - I just tend to use MS Fakes as it's reliable and built into (the more expensive versions of) Visual Studio.

Comment: @RB. Thanks for your quick comment. But if I use Microsoft fakes it will also force me to edit the main code. how can I avoid this.

Comment: No it won't. Your unit test is written to make any call to InformationController.GetTermsAndConds return a canned response. You only have to change unit test code...

Comment: @RB. Thanks again. I'm referring to a doc on Microsoft fakes right now. can you give me any directions to a quick find.

Comment: I've added an answer with sample code. Your unit-test is a bit odd though - it calls `controller.GetTerm` twice...?

Comment: @RB. I've corrected it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a Fakes assembly for the assembly containing `InformationController`. Then you can re-write your unit-test method as so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTerm_FromGetTerm()
{
    var controller = new ServController();

    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        MyAssembly.Fakes.ShimInteractionController.GetTermsAndConds = () => SomeCannedResponse();

        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.GetTerm();
        var result = controller.GetTerm(); // Why do you call GetTerm twice?!
        Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I really appreciate. to use this I need to add Microsoft  fake to my references in the unit test project Aren't I.....? or is there any file to include with this...?

Comment: Search for "Add Fakes assembly" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx - this gives a good tutorial on actually using Fakes. Note that you will need a version of Visual Studio higher than Professional - other Faking tools are available if that's a problem...

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. I'm pretty sure that I am on the right track now. I'm using VS Ultimate 2013 version 12.0.31101.00. Are MS fakes available in VS products after that or that included.

Comment: I found the solution using Microsoft Fakes. Again thank you very much **@RB.**  for your help.